# Table of Interactions - Case with pets and houses

Tags: r, combinations, interaction

I have a list of houses and a list of animal species.

```
houses = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,5)
animals = c('cat','dog','cat','dog','rat', 'cat', 'spider', 'snake', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat')
```

I am trying to create a function that returns an upper triangular table that indicates for each pet, the number of times that it was observed to live in the same house than the other animal species. Does it make sense?

For the above example, the table should look like this (hope there's no mistake!) :

```
    dog   rat   spider   snake
cat  1     2      1        1      
dog        0      0        0
rat               1        1
spider                     1
```

---

Note: This function should work for any two vectors of same lengths, whatever if they contain numbers or string

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `table` and `crossprod`:

```
out <- crossprod(table(houses, animals))
out[lower.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
out
#         animals
# animals  cat dog rat snake spider
#   cat     NA   1   2     1      1
#   dog     NA  NA   0     0      0
#   rat     NA  NA  NA     1      1
#   snake   NA  NA  NA    NA      1
#   spider  NA  NA  NA    NA     NA
```

Since the output is a `matrix` you can suppress the printing of the `NA` values directly in `print`:

```
print(out,na.print="")
#         animals
# animals  cat dog rat snake spider
#   cat          1   2     1      1
#   dog              0     0      0
#   rat                    1      1
#   snake                         1
#   spider
```

Comment: You can save one line by using `diag=TRUE` in `out[lower.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] <- NA` ;)

Comment: @Jilber, True. I always forget about that argument in `diag`. Thanks.

Comment: Very elegant solution in three lines! Thanks a lot. Note: One can also use `as.table(..)` to print without the `NA`

Comment: And to get the requested output it would be: `print(out[-5,-1], na.print="")`

Comment: Just adding a sparse alternative of this answer in case any memory footprint can be reduced during tabulation: `Matrix::crossprod(xtabs(~ houses + animals, sparse = TRUE))`