# Table of interactions - case with pets and houses 2

Tags: r, combinations, interaction

I want to extend the solution of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) where @AnandaMahto gave a very elegant solution to my problem.

For this new function, I'd like that if there are several times the same species in the same house, it will count only one observation. One house with two `cats` and one `rat` does not create two observations between `cat` and `rat` but only one (As shown below)

In this example, there are two `rats` in the house number 4. As already said, I do not want to consider two observations between `rat` and `cat` and between `spider` and `rat` but only one observation between `rat` and `cat` and one observation between `spider` and `rat`

```
houses = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,5)
animals = c('cat','dog','cat','dog','rat', 'cat', 'spider', 'rat', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat')
```

@AnandaMahto's solution would return this:

```
        dog rat spider
   cat   1   3      1
   dog       0      0
   rat              2
```

But I would like to get this:

```
        dog rat spider
   cat   1   2      1
   dog       0      0
   rat              1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all values `> 0` from `table` equal to "1" before using `crossprod`:

```
(table(houses, animals) > 0) *1
#       animals
# houses cat dog rat spider
#      1   1   1   0      0
#      2   1   0   0      0
#      3   0   1   0      0
#      4   1   0   1      1
#      5   1   0   1      0
#      6   1   0   0      0

out <- crossprod((table(houses, animals) > 0) *1)
out[lower.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
as.table(out)
#         animals
# animals  cat dog rat spider
#   cat          1   2      1
#   dog              0      0
#   rat                     1
#   spider
```

---

To get to the desired output, since we know that the first column and the last row will be empty, and since you already figured out on your own that `as.table` would take care of not printing the `NA` values, continuing from above, you can do:

```
out <- as.table(out[-nrow(out), -1])
out
#        animals
# animals dog rat spider
#     cat   1   2      1
#     dog       0      0
#     rat              1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more time!