# Get number of same individuals for different groups

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I have a data set with individuals (*ID*) that can be part of more than one group.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  ID = rep(1:5, c(3:1, 2:3)),
  Group = c("A", "B", "C", "B",
            "C", "A", "A", "C",
            "A", "B", "C")
)
DT
#     ID Group
#  1:  1     A
#  2:  1     B
#  3:  1     C
#  4:  2     B
#  5:  2     C
#  6:  3     A
#  7:  4     A
#  8:  4     C
#  9:  5     A
# 10:  5     B
# 11:  5     C
```

I want to know the sum of identical individuals for 2 groups.

The result should look like this:

```
  Group.1    Group.2    Sum
    A           B        2
    A           C        3
    B           C        3
```

Where *Sum* indicates the number of individuals the two groups have in common.

Comment: See, also, this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses). You can combine that answer with `as.data.frame(as.table())` and `complete.cases`.

Comment: `out <- with(dt, crossprod(table(ID, Group))); out[lower.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] <- NA; na.omit(as.data.frame.table(out))` from the link above

Comment: @ alexis_laz and @rawr also nice solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
# size-1 IDs can't contribute; skip
DT[ , if (.N > 1) 
  # simplify = FALSE returns a list;
  #   transpose turns the 3-length list of 2-length vectors
  #   into a length-2 list of 3-length vectors (efficiently)
  transpose(combn(Group, 2L, simplify = FALSE)), by = ID
  ][ , .(Sum = .N), keyby = .(Group.1 = V1, Group.2 = V2)]
```

With output:

```
#    Group.1 Group.2 Sum
# 1:       A       B   2
# 2:       A       C   3
# 3:       B       C   3
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `DT[ , as.data.table(combinat::combn2(unique(Group))), by = ID][, .(Sum = .N), keyby = .(Group.1 = V1, Group.2 = V2)]`. `combinat::combn2()` doesn't throw an error in case of `.N < 2` and no `transpose()` is required.

Comment: @Uwe cool :) taking a glance at the [source](https://github.com/cran/combinat/blob/master/R/combn2.R#L4) of `combn2`, I see it just does a `t` internally, so I guess `transpose` will be more efficient :) (ps last edited 1994!? :o )

Comment: A benchmark comparison would be quite interesting (if not already posted on SO).

Comment: @Uwe was thinking the same, but a way to benchmark didn't jump immediately to mind so i gave up :p

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016), `data.table` has gained the ability to do *non-equi joins*. So, a *self non-equi join* can be used:

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.8+
setDT(DT)[, Group:= factor(Group)]
DT[DT, on = .(ID, Group < Group), nomatch = 0L, .(ID, x.Group, i.Group)][
  , .N, by = .(x.Group, i.Group)]
```

> ```
>    x.Group i.Group N
> 1:       A       B 2
> 2:       A       C 3
> 3:       B       C 3
> ```

#### Explanantion

The *non-equi join* on `ID, Group < Group` is a `data.table` version of `combn()` (but applied group-wise):

```
DT[DT, on = .(ID, Group < Group), nomatch = 0L, .(ID, x.Group, i.Group)]
```

> ```
>    ID x.Group i.Group
> 1:  1       A       B
> 2:  1       A       C
> 3:  1       B       C
> 4:  2       B       C
> 5:  4       A       C
> 6:  5       A       B
> 7:  5       A       C
> 8:  5       B       C
> ```

Comment: nice use of self NE join! very SQL :p ; thanks for bringing this Q to my attention, my answer was quite sloppy and I got a chance to improve it :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I' trying to learn SQL through `data.table` ;-)

Comment: well then, your next assignment is to implement my own approach in SQL :p

Answer (score 2):

We self-join with the same dataset `on` 'ID', subset the rows where the 'Group' columns are different, get the nrows (`.N`), grouped by the 'Group' columns, sort the 'Group.1' and 'Group.2' columns by row using `pmin/pmax` and get the `unique` value of 'N'.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
 DT[DT, on='ID', allow.cartesian=TRUE][Group!=i.Group, .N ,.(Group, i.Group)][, 
      list(Sum=unique(N)) ,.(Group.1=pmin(Group, i.Group), Group.2=pmax(Group, i.Group))]

#   Group.1 Group.2 Sum
#1:       A       B   2
#2:       A       C   3
#3:       B       C   3
```

Or as mentioned in the comments by @MichaelChirico and @Frank, we can convert 'Group' to `factor` class, subset the rows based on `as.integer(Group) < as.integer(i.Group)`, group by 'Group', 'i.Group' and get the nrow (`.N`)

```
DT[, Group:= factor(Group)]
DT[DT, on='ID', allow.cartesian=TRUE][as.integer(Group) < as.integer(i.Group), .N, 
                       by = .(Group.1= Group, Group.2= i.Group)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @akrun I like your approach but I would do the following: first convert `Group` to a `factor` (if it's not already), then simply add `as.integer(Group)<as.integer(i.Group)` to the logical statement in the second `[ ]` pair. Then you don't need to worry about this `pmax` mess.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Michael. I'd do `dt[dt, on="ID", allow.cartesian=TRUE][Group < i.Group, .N, by=.(G1=Group,G2=i.Group)]` on the assumption that folks are not listed multiple times in the same group (so `uniqueN` is not needed).

Answer (score 1):

yet another solution (base R):

```
tmp <- split(DT, DT[, 'Group'])
ans <- apply(combn(LETTERS[1 : 3], 2), 2, FUN = function(ind){
            out <- length(intersect(tmp[[ind[1]]][, 1], tmp[[ind[2]]][, 1]))
            c(group1 = ind[1], group2 = ind[2], sum_ = out) 
                }
            )

data.frame(t(ans))

#  group1 group2 sum_
#1      A      B    2
#2      A      C    3
#3      B      C    3
```

first split data into list of groups, then for each unique pairwise combinations of two groups see how many subjects in common they have, using `length(intersect(...`.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers above.
Just an alternative using `dplyr` in case you, or someone else, is interested.

```
library(dplyr)

cmb = combn(unique(dt$Group),2)

data.frame(g1 = cmb[1,],
           g2 = cmb[2,]) %>%
  group_by(g1,g2) %>%
  summarise(l=length(intersect(DT[DT$Group==g1,]$ID,
                               DT[DT$Group==g2,]$ID)))

    #       g1     g2     l
    #    (fctr) (fctr) (int)
    # 1      A      B     2
    # 2      A      C     3
    # 3      B      C     3
```