# Finding Number of Groups that Contain Specific Pairs in Data Frame

Tags: r

I am trying to find the number of groups in a data frame that contain specific pairs. Here is an example of what I have done and the desired output.

#### Creating the data

```
df=data.frame(c("Sam","Sam","Sam","Jason", "Jason", "Kelly", "Kelly"),
c("e","f","g","h", "h", "e", "f"))

names(df)=c('name','value')
```

#### Not interested in looking at the pairs which do not occur within at least one specific name, so I drop those observations before generating the pairs

```
df=df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),]

df=df[ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$name, FUN=length)>1,]

pairs=t(combn(unique(df$value), 2))
```

#### Now I have two objects that look like this

```
   name value
1   Sam     e
2   Sam     f
3   Sam     g
6 Kelly     e
7 Kelly     f

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] e    f   
[2,] e    g   
[3,] f    g
```

#### My Desired Output

```
   pair.1    pair.2  occurrences
1   e          f         2
2   e          g         1
3   f          g         1
```

Comment: Take a look into the `igraph` package. I'm sure you can find some dupes around here. And please don't embed into your MWE lines that mess up with ones environment.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) should be helpful for start; and adding a `merge`: `merge(data.frame(val1 = pairs[, 1L], val2 = pairs[, 2L]), setNames(as.data.frame(as.table(crossprod(table(df)))), c("val1", "val2", "freq")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `merge` the dataset with itself by 'name', `sort` the 'value' columns by  'row', convert the dataset to `data.table`, remove the rows with the same 'value' elements, grouped by the 'value' columns, get the nrow (`.N`) and divide by 2.

```
d1 <- merge(df, df, by.x='name', by.y='name')
d1[-1] <- t(apply(d1[-1], 1, sort))
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[value.x!=value.y][,.N/2 ,.(value.x, value.y)]
#   value.x value.y V1
#1:       e       f  2
#2:       e       g  1
#3:       f       g  1
```

---

Or using a similar method as in @jeremycg's post

```
 setDT(df)[df, on='name', allow.cartesian=TRUE
     ][as.character(value)< as.character(i.value), .N, .(value, i.value)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer using `dplyr`. See the comments inline for explanation:

```
library(dplyr) #load dplyr
df %>% #your data
 left_join(df, by = "name") %>% #merge against your own data
 filter(as.character(value.x) < as.character(value.y)) %>% #filter out any where the two are equal, and make sure we only have one of each pair
 group_by(value.x, value.y) %>% #group by the two vars
 summarise(n()) #count them

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: value.x [?]

  value.x value.y   n()
   (fctr)  (fctr) (int)
1       e       f     2
2       e       g     1
3       f       g     1
```