# Create matrix based upon group membership

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a matrix that indicates group membership from a dataframe. For example, a NxN matrix where 1 means a neighborhood is within the same city as another neighborhood and 0 means the neighborhoods are part of a different city. For example:

```
hoodid <- c(1:10) 
cityid <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
df <- data.frame(hoodid, cityid)
df

#    hoodid cityid
# 1       1      1
# 2       2      1
# 3       3      1
# 4       4      2
# 5       5      2
# 6       6      3
# 7       7      3
# 8       8      3
# 9       9      3
# 10     10      3
```

The desired outcome is:

```
# 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
# 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
# 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
# 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
# 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 
# 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: You might be interested in the igraph package, designed for this sort of thing

Comment: Can you give any more clue as to which part of igraph would help?

Comment: `from_adjacency` will convert your adjacency matrix into a graph. From there, you can take advantage of the graph algorithms that are usually used for analysis of data like this.

Comment: I'll look into that too. Thanks for the help Frank.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) helpful too; `tcrossprod(table(df))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
library(Matrix)
m = do.call(bdiag, lapply(
  lengths(split(df$cityid, df$cityid)), 
  function(n) 1 - diag(n)
))

# 10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                          
#  [1,] . 1 1 . . . . . . .
#  [2,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
#  [3,] 1 1 . . . . . . . .
#  [4,] . . . . 1 . . . . .
#  [5,] . . . 1 . . . . . .
#  [6,] . . . . . . 1 1 1 1
#  [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1
#  [8,] . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
#  [9,] . . . . . 1 1 1 . 1
# [10,] . . . . . 1 1 1 1 .
```

This assumes that your data is sorted by `cityid` first and doesn't have duplicates or any other oddities.

You can `as.matrix(m)` if you want a vanilla matrix.

Comment: Excellent. This is right on, assuming the sorting on cityid (the group variable) first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Frank's solution worked for me, but I wanted to come up with a more general solution. Frank's solution requires group member's to be ordered. Also, if you create a very large matrix (as I did), `lapply` leave a lot of cache in the memory that cannot be cleaned with garbage collection (`gc()`).

Required packages: `igraph` and `data.table` (not necessary, but it is faster).

```r
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)

hoodid <- c(1:10) 
cityid <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
df <- data.frame(hoodid, cityid)
df
# hoodid cityid
# 1       1      1
# 2       2      1
# 3       3      1
# 4       4      2
# 5       5      2
# 6       6      3
# 7       7      3
# 8       8      3
# 9       9      3
# 10     10      3

city_list = unique(df$cityid)
edges = list()
for (i in 1:length(city_list)) {
   edges[[i]] = data.table(t(combn(df[df$cityid == city_list[i], 'hoodid'], 2)))
}
edges = rbindlist(edges)

g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(edges), directed = F)
g = get.adjacency(g)
g

# 10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 
# [1,] . 1 1 . . . . . . .
# [2,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
# [3,] 1 1 . . . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . 1 . . . . .
# [5,] . . . 1 . . . . . .
# [6,] . . . . . . 1 1 1 1
# [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1
# [8,] . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
# [9,] . . . . . 1 1 1 . 1
# [10,] . . . . . 1 1 1 1 .
```

Without data.table

```r
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)

hoodid <- c(1:10) 
cityid <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
df <- data.frame(hoodid, cityid)
df
# hoodid cityid
# 1       1      1
# 2       2      1
# 3       3      1
# 4       4      2
# 5       5      2
# 6       6      3
# 7       7      3
# 8       8      3
# 9       9      3
# 10     10      3

edges = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
for (i in unique(df$cityid)) {
  edges = rbind(edges, t(combn(df[df$cityid == i, 'hoodid'], 2)))
}

g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(edges), directed = F)
g = get.adjacency(g)
g

# 10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 
# [1,] . 1 1 . . . . . . .
# [2,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
# [3,] 1 1 . . . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . 1 . . . . .
# [5,] . . . 1 . . . . . .
# [6,] . . . . . . 1 1 1 1
# [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1
# [8,] . . . . . 1 1 . 1 1
# [9,] . . . . . 1 1 1 . 1
# [10,] . . . . . 1 1 1 1 .
```