# Creating a particular cross-tab in R?

Tags: r, crosstab, summary

I have a dataframe that contains information about financial contributions to political candidates (denoted in the data by "cand") and political organizations (denoted in the data by "comm"). The dataframe also includes a unique ID for each contributor, with each row in the data denoting one contribution made. What I want to do is get a crosstab that shows, for each political (non-candidate) organization, how many donors to those organizations also contributed to each political candidate in the dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
 contributor ID .      organization
 1                     cand1
 2                     cand2
 3                     comm1
 3                     cand1
 4                     cand1
 5                     cand2
 5                     cand1
 5                     comm2
```

What I want to be able to create is something like this:

```
  Comm .              Cand
               Cand1 .     Cand2
  Comm1        1           0
  Comm2        1           1
```

(Because 1 person -- ID #3 -- contributed to both comm1 and cand1, and 1 person -- ID #5 -- contributed to comm1, cand1, and cand2.)

I have thought about ways to do this using aggregate or dplyr, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: If memory is available, you could start with `crossprod(table(dat))` -as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses)- and subset accordingly like `crossprod(table(dat))[startsWith(levels(dat$org), "comm"), startsWith(levels(dat$org), "cand")]`

Comment: Thanks for this. I get the following error with this code: Error in table(table) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Along the same lines, you might give the sparse alternative a try -- `library(Matrix); tab = xtabs( ~ contributorID + organization, dat, sparse = TRUE); crossprod(tab[, startsWith(colnames(tab), "comm")], tab[, startsWith(colnames(tab), "cand")])`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, could you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Yoou need to use something like tidyr.  You need to make a variable for each committee and one for each candidate.     Your data is already in long format, but what you now need to do is create a  wide data frame using organization and the donor ID as the unique id. The you can do crosstabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs = read.table(text = "contributor organization
1 cand1
2 cand2
3 comm1
3 cand1
4 cand1
5 cand2
5 cand1
5 comm2", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

# select only comms with their contributor
comms = dfs[grep("^comm", dfs$organization), ]
colnames(comms)[2] = "comms"
# select only cands
cands = dfs[grep("^cand", dfs$organization), ]
colnames(cands)[2] = "cands"

# combine comms and candidates
new_dfs = merge(comms, cands, all = TRUE)
with(new_dfs, table(comms, cands))
```

#### Update. Try to avoid creation of large matrix with `table`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dfs = read.table(text = "contributor organization
1 cand1
2 cand2
3 comm1
3 cand1
4 cand1
5 cand2
5 cand1
5 comm2", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

# select only comms with their contributor
comms = dfs %>% filter(grepl("^comm", organization))

# select only cands
cands = dfs %>% 
    filter(grepl("^cand", organization)) %>% 
    mutate(
        value = 1
    ) %>% 
    spread(key  = organization, value = value, fill = 0)

left_join(comms, cands)
```

Comment: I understand the intuition behind this code, but am running into a similar as with other suggestions: Error in table(comms, cands) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution using `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `table()`. First we calculate a summary of the number of contributors to a `cand` *and* a `com`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_summary <- 
df %>% mutate(ct = 1) %>% spread(organization, ct) %>% 
transmute(
  comm1_cand1 = ifelse(cand1 + comm1 > 0, 1, 0),
  comm2_cand1 = ifelse(cand1 + comm2 > 0, 1, 0),
  comm1_cand2 = ifelse(cand2 + comm1 > 0, 1, 0),
  comm2_cand2 = ifelse(cand2 + comm2 > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
gather() %>%
separate(key, into = c("comm", "cand"), sep = "_")
```

This gives a two way categorical data frame that looks like this:

```
#    comm  cand value
#1  comm1 cand1    NA
#2  comm1 cand1    NA
#3  comm1 cand1     1
#4  comm1 cand1    NA
#5  comm1 cand1    NA
#6  comm2 cand1    NA
#7  comm2 cand1    NA
# etc
```

Now we make our two-way table from the data.

```
table(df_summary)

#   cand
#comm    cand1 cand2
#  comm1     1     0
#  comm2     1     1
```

Comment: This solution seems great, but I did get the following error: "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows..." Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: OK. Can you provide a bigger sample of your data that causes this problem? I only used your original 8 observations thinking it would be scaleable, but it seems not.