# Counting appearances of combination of elements in R

Tags: r, count, combn

I have a big client who purchases from me in a high frequency. I would like to know which combinations of products he often purchases together. For example, every time he buys *product A* he also buys *product W*. And the same happens for other combination of products.

My goal is to identify which are these combinations of products so that I can offer *product W* to my other clients who purchase only *product A* (maybe they are buying *product W* from my competition without knowing that I sell it).

My data looks like this

```
   codclient  codproduct            quant         date
1      101249     A                4.1600     2016-10-01
2      101249     W                1.3880     2016-10-01
3      101249     B                1.5268     2016-10-01
4      101249     A                0.8328     2016-11-01
5      101249     W                2.9148     2016-11-01
6      101249     B                2.7760     2016-11-01
7      101249     C                1.8750     2016-11-01
8      101250     A                0.6940     2016-10-01
9      101250     A                7.0000     2016-11-01
10     101251     B               12.0000     2016-11-01
11     101251     C             1000.0000     2016-11-01
12     101252     W             1000.0000     2016-11-01
```

Using `intersect` or `Reduce(intersect, list = (products_by_month))` I can only see which items are always purchased.

As of now, what I have in mind is counting how many times each combination of products appears in client 49 purchase account across months, then choose those baskets as reference to suggest for my other clients.

I can create the vector of product combinations using `combn` (every combination of two, or three products would be enough) but I am still missing how to count the times they appear together in each vector of purchased products for each month.

Any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: You might find something helpful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/r-table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) -- e.g. `crossprod(table(month, product))`

Comment: I'd probably make a complete graph with products as nodes; set the weight between a pair of products = # times they are purchased together; and use some standard graph tools to find clusters (... I'm just assuming these exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been wanting to delve into market basket analytics for a while now and I know there is a specific package for this in r:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html

This may or may not help you but I figured I'd throw it out there just in case.

Comment: This does much more than I was considering. Thanks

Comment: No prob! It really is a fascinating topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with dplyr:

```
spread(filter(df,codClient == 101249),codproduct,quant)

     codclient      date      A       B        C         W
1       101249 10/1/2016 4.1600  1.5268       NA    1.3880
2       101249 11/1/2016 0.8328  2.7760    1.875    2.9148
```