# Find number of matching rows between dataframes in a list

Tags: r

I have a list containing `N` dataframes. For this question we look at `N=3` for simplicity,

```
asd<-list()

asd[[1]]<-data.frame("one"=c(1:3), "two"=c("a","b","c"))
asd[[2]]<-data.frame("one"=c(3:5), "two"=c("c","b","a"))
asd[[3]]<-data.frame("one"=c(5:7), "two"=c("a","b","c"))
```

I'd like to compare these dataframes to each other and get a `N x N` matrix out whose entries `(i,j)` tell me how many rows are identical between data frame `i` and `j`.

So, for the above we get a 3x3 matrix with elements `(i,j)`

```
(1,1)=(2,2)=(3,3) 3 (3 rows are identical)
(1,2)=(2,1)       1 (1 row is identical)
(1,3)=(3,1)       0 (0 rows are identical)
(2,3)=(3,2)       1 (0 row is identical)
```

Which function can I use for this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
sapply(seq_along(asd), function(i) 
   sapply(seq_along(asd), function(j) sum(rowSums(asd[[i]]==asd[[j]])==2)))
```

---

Or it could be

```
sapply(seq_along(asd), function(i) 
    sapply(seq_along(asd), function(j) sum(duplicated(rbind(asd[[i]], asd[[j]])))))
```

Or another option is

```
`dim<-`(unlist(do.call(Map, c(f= function(...) 
        sum(duplicated(rbind(...))), expand.grid(asd, asd)))), c(3, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice suggestion. Can it be generalized to the situation where `asd[[1]], asd[[2]]` and `asd[[3]]` have different lengths?

Comment: @BillyJean I guess my second and third suggestion should work for datasets that have different number of rows

Answer (score 2):

The "list" structure might be more convenient to be replaced with a "data.frame":

```
asd2 = cbind(do.call(rbind, asd), 
             df = rep(seq_along(asd), sapply(asd, nrow)))
```

If each row of the `asd` "data.frame"s could be mapped to a single number, then the problem could be made simpler:

```
r = tapply(1:nrow(asd2), asd2[c("one", "two")])
```

And, then, following the [`crossprod(table())` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) (or a variation with a sparse matrix):

```
library(Matrix)
crossprod(xtabs( ~ r + df, asd2, sparse = TRUE))
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#  1 2 3
#1 3 1 .
#2 1 3 1
#3 . 1 3
```

Comment: Great approach with `crossprod`.  You always comes up with some ideas I couldn't think of