# How to create a pairwise matrix with counts of matching entries for comparisons of all levels of one factor in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a two column dataframe of two variables that are factors:

df

```
PLOT  INTERACTION 
 A    interact_type_1
 A    interact_type_2
 B    interact_type_3
 B    interact_type_4 
 C    interact_type_1
 D    interact_type_4
 E    interact_type_1
 E    interact_type_2
 E    interact_type_3
 E    interact_type_4
```

I need a pairwise matrix where nrows and mcolumns are the unique levels of Variable 1 (PLOTS). The matrix fill will include the counts of INTERACTION matches among each combination of the levels of PLOT. Since it is a similarity matrix there would be only 1/2 fill of the matrix, so the same PLOTS and 1/2 of the matrix will be filled with NAs. In this example, the output matrix would look like:

```
output


   A   B    C    D    E

A NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

B 0   NA    NA   NA   NA

C 1   0    NA    NA   NA

D 0   1    0    NA    NA

E 2   2    1    1     NA
```

I have tried changing it from long to wide format then using a loop:

```
 df<- spread(df, df$PLOT, df$INTERACTION) 


 similarity.matrix<-matrix(nrow=ncol(F.data),ncol=ncol(F.data))


 for( in 1:ncol(F.data)){
  matches<-F.data[,col]==F.data
  match.counts<-colSums(matches)
  match.counts[col]<-0 # Set the same column comparison to zero.
  similarity.matrix[,col]<-match.counts
   }
```

but I get an error with the first line stating Error: Invalid column specification.

I appreciate your time and help! Thank you.

Comment: See a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses) -- `tcrossprod(table(df))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table of Interactions - Case with pets and houses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891278/table-of-interactions-case-with-pets-and-houses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
x = xtabs(~PLOT+INTERACTION,d)
        INTERACTION
    PLOT interact_type_1 interact_type_2 interact_type_3 interact_type_4
       A               1               1               0               0
       B               0               0               1               1
       C               1               0               0               0
       D               0               0               0               1
       E               1               1               1               1
```

Find the combinations of two among `PLOT` using `combn`:

```
n = length(unique(d$PLOT))
c = combn(1:n,2)
```

Then construct your matrix and fill its lower half:

```
m = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
## for each possible combination of two present in c, we find for the corresponding rows in x how many 1s they have in common using sum(x[y[1],]*x[y[2],])
m[lower.tri(m)] = apply(c,2,function(y) sum(x[y[1],]*x[y[2],]))
```

This returns:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    0   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    0    1    0   NA   NA
[5,]    2    2    1    1   NA
```